# Returning categories where the count of an attribute is greater than 0 in RStudio - Barplot

Tags: r, null, bar-chart

I am new to R so sorry about the basic question.

i want to do a barplot on categorical data based on the amount of occurrences of a value.
its based on the google App store data and i want to see in a bar chart how many occurrences under for example "Games", "Arts&Design" etc.
My issue is that there are 20 odd categories (many of which have 0 occurrences because i have taken a subset["topPerforming"] of the top performing apps) so when i plot barplot its very difficult to read as it shows all categories, including all categories with 0 occurrences.

I would like to plot a barplot based on the top 5 performing categories but i am having issues doing so.
when i try do topPerforming$category > 5, i get an error saying "In Ops.factor(topPerforming$Category, 0) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors"

```
table(topPerforming$Category)
table <- table(topPerforming$Category) # viewing the number of occurences in each category
barplot(prop.table(table(topPerforming$Category)))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well, without a sample dataset, you could use a `dplyr` chain to add the number of occurrences and then filter the data set, maybe:

```
new_data = topPerforming %>% group_by(Category) %>% add_count %>% filter(.,N>5)
```

If you have a dput snippet or example data, it should be easy enough to check